# Android studio - Error en todo el código Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Yo y un amigo estamos trabajando en un proyecto, pero nos tenemos que estar pasando el proyecto de Android cada vez que sea necesario. Cada vez que lo vuelvo a descargar lo importo, pero esta última vez que me pasó el proyecto me sucede esto.

Puedo utilizarlo, compila el programa (lo cual me extraña), pero no puedo codificar a gusto porque no sabré si tendré un error hasta que corra la aplicación.

¿Qué puedo hacer?
No me funciona reconstruyendo el proyecto, limpiarlo, reiniciando el programa, la computadora, cerrar el proyecto

[image: Pantalla de cómo me aparece]

Comment: Has probado haciendo un Graddle del proyecto?

Comment: No estoy seguro de si es muy urgente lo que tienen que hacer, pero para este tipo de casos [github](https://github.com/) ahorra muchísimos problemas.

Comment: Lo que hacen no esta bien de ninguna forma. Deben hacer uso de un sistema de control de versiones para poder trabajar de forma colaborativa. te recomiendo desde ya que aprendas a usar Git para ello. aqui un link para que lo revises https://androidstudiofaqs.com/tutoriales/como-usar-git-en-android-studio. Y otro para que veas que es git. https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/que-es-git

Comment: No has definido el path correcto del Android SDK o tienes errores en los recursos, revisa principalmente los layouts. Te recomiendo agregar más información, ¿Como lo importas? ¿De donde lo descargas? @RaúlAlvarez

Comment: Muchas gracias @Galbi, no sabe del apuro que me sacó.

Comment: @JhonFredyTrujilloOrtega gracias por el consejo, no conocía ese potencial de Github, lo tomaré en cuenta y lon hablaré con mi colega.

Comment: @Jorgesys nos lo pasabamos por GoogleDrive y lo importaba desde la pestaña de la esquina.

Comment: @RaúlAlvarez  ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude solucionar el problema.
Gracias a Galbi por el comentario.

Mi solución fue el botón de sincronizar con el Gradle, como el que muestro en la imagen.

[image: Pantalla]